# How filter seq of tuples by compare two values in tuple?

Tags: scala

I have Seq

```
Seq((date1, date2), (date1, date3))
```

I need filter this Seq by compare  two dates into tuple. For example: date1.isBefore(date2)

Comment: Can you give sample output for this?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Do you want to only keep elements where the first date is before the other?

Comment: Seq(("2020-09-01", "2020-09-01"), ("2020-09-01", "2020-09-02"), ("2020-09-02", "2020-09-01"), ("2020-09-01", "2020-10-01")) => Seq(("2020-09-01", "2020-09-02"), ("2020-09-01", "2020-10-01"))

Comment: Yes. I want to get another sequence in which the first date is before the second date of the tuple

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may be helpful. A couple different examples at the end that swap the order of the dates compared that could be useful.

```
scala> val date1 = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
val date1: java.util.Date = Wed Sep 23 11:21:24 PDT 2020

scala> val date2 = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
val date2: java.util.Date = Wed Sep 23 11:21:28 PDT 2020

scala> val xs = Seq((date1,date2))
val xs: Seq[(java.util.Date, java.util.Date)] = List((Wed Sep 23 11:21:24 PDT 2020,Wed Sep 23 11:21:28 PDT 2020))

scala> xs.filter(t => t._1.before(t._2))
val res1: Seq[(java.util.Date, java.util.Date)] = List((Wed Sep 23 11:21:24 PDT 2020,Wed Sep 23 11:21:28 PDT 2020))

scala> xs.filter(t => t._2.before(t._1))
val res2: Seq[(java.util.Date, java.util.Date)] = List()
```

Comment: How to get the min value from _1 and max value from _2 after filtering?

I need two values


`val minDate from xs.filter(t => t._1.before(t._2))._1 

val maxDate rom xs.filter(t => t._1.before(t._2))._2`

Comment: You can access the `Tuple` elements with `._1` and `._2`. Accessing the seq can be done with `head` to get the first element or `(i)` where `i` is the index of the element. An example would be `xs.filter(t => t._1.before(t._2)).head._1`

Comment: But after `xs.filter(t => t._1.before(t._2))` I have Seq(Tuples (LocaDate, LocalDate)) and I need 1 min value from all first elements and 1 max value from all second elements of tuples

Comment: In my example:
`val xs = Seq(("2020-09-01", "2020-09-01"), ("2020-09-01", "2020-09-02"), ("2020-09-02", "2020-09-01"), ("2020-09-01", "2020-10-01"))

val xs2 = xs.filter(t => t._1.before(t._2)) //Seq(("2020-09-01", "2020-09-02"), ("2020-09-01", "2020-10-01")) `

I need
`val minDate = min(xs2._1) // "2020-09-01"
val maxDate = max(xs2._2) //"2020-10-01"`

Comment: For that use case it is probably easier to transform the tuples to a `List` then take the `min` of minimums and the `max` of the maximums. Adding this `.map(t => List(t._1, t._2)).transpose` to `res1` or `res2` above will convert to a `List` then `tranpose` to get a `List` of the minimums and maximums.  Then you can use `min` and `max` on the result.

Comment: Here is a simplified use case with numbers to make it easier to visualize: `scala> Seq((11,21), (12, 22), (13,23)).map(t => List(t._1, t._2)).transpose.head.min
val res24: Int = 11`

Comment: Good. But for LocalDate values I have error "No implicits found for parameter cmp: Ordering[LocalDate]"